# How to extract non-matching text in two documents

Tags: python, diff

Lets say I have two strings.

> a = 'I am Sam. I love cooking.'
>
> b = 'I am sam. I used to drink a lot.'

I am calculating their similarity score using :

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
s = SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == " ",a,b)
print s.ratio()
```

Now I want to print non-matching sentences in both strings. Like this

> a = 'I love cooking.'
>
> b = 'I used to drink a lot.'

Any suggestion like what module or approach I can use to do that? I saw one module in difflib https://pymotw.com/2/difflib/ But in this it prints with (+,-,!,...) I don't want output in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very simple script . But i hope it gives you idea of how to do:

```
a = 'I am Sam. I love cooking.'    
b = 'I am sam. I used to drink a lot.'

a= a.split('.')
b=b.split('.')

ca=len(a)
cb=len(b)

if ca>cb:l=cb
else :l=ca

c=0

while c<l:
    if a[c].upper() == b[c].upper():pass
    else:print b[c]+'.'
    c=c+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `difflib`. You can easily post-process the output of `difflib.Differ`, to strip off the first two characters of each unit and convert them to any format you want. Or you can work with the alignments returned by `SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks`, and generate your own output.

Here's how you might do it. If that's not what you want, **edit your question** to provide a less simplistic example of comparison and the output format you need.

```
differ = difflib.Differ()
for line in differ.compare(list1, list2):
    if line.startswith("-"):
        print("a="+line[2:])
    elif line.startswith("+"):
        print("b="+line[2:])
    # else just ignore the line
```